# What is the difference between a Label and a Property in Neo4j?

Tags: properties, neo4j, label

I'm fairly new to Neo4j, but very experienced in RDBMS design and development.  Trying to understand the difference between a Label and a Property in Neo4j.  Nothing I've read seems to differentiate between the two, in fact, I find that the terms are often used interchangeably.  I assume there must be a difference, otherwise the Wise Men and Women of Neo4j would not have created both...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11):

A Property is a key-value pair that is part of a Relationship or a Node.

A Label is a name/tag/category you assign to one or several Nodes.
Note that the nodes with similar labels do not necessarily share the same set of property keys and/or property value types.

Constraints and indices are defined against Labels.
(Though legacy index APIs - they are pre-v2, i.e. pre-Labels - work only with Properties).

From a filesystem perspective, regular label lookups are normally faster than regular property lookups because labels are stored and normalized within their own file (i.e. "label store") vs. spread and repeated across all corresponding nodes for properties.

Comment: Labels are like tags or categories that you want to put your node in, they allow us also to attach metadata to the nodes (like indexes, constraints and more in the future)

Comment: Thanks very much for your replies, I appreciate it.  I've also done some more reading since I posted the question, and I have a better understanding of the differences.  But I'm still puzzled by their apparent redundancy.  Sure, I can create a Node with a Label of "Person", and another Node with a Label of "Vehicle", but couldn't I achieve the same thing by creating a Property called "Type" and give it a value of "Person" on one Node and "Vehicle" on another Node?  It seems like a Label is just a special type of Property (key-value pair) where you basically have a "key-less" value.

Comment: Also, my understanding is that you can assign indexes, constraints, etc. to both Labels and Properties, so What then is the advantage of defining something as a Label as opposed to a Property?

Comment: @David : from a filesystem perspective, labels have their own "store", which means labels are normalized and allows faster lookups than regular property lookups.

Constraints and (new) indexes are defined against a label (and some property).

Comment: Thanks Rolf.  That's the differentiator I was looking for.